# How to Add Production Ready ReactiveCocoa or Futures / Promises Into Swift 2 iOS

Tags: swift, functional-programming, future, reactive-cocoa

I saw a [Back to the Futures](https://realm.io/news/swift-summit-javier-soto-futures) presentation by [Javier Soto](https://twitter.com/Javi) that got me excited about [ReactiveCocoa](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa) and Functional Reactive Programming aka FRP. [Ash Furrow](https://twitter.com/ashfurrow)'s [Functional Reactive Awesomeness With Swift](https://realm.io/news/altconf-ash-furrow-functional-reactive-swift/) presentation greatly helped convince me as well.

As of Nov 2015, I use the latest Xcode and [Swift](https://developer.apple.com/swift/resources/) (Xcode 7.1 Swift 2 for iOS 8+). For a new project coming up in a couple days, I would like to use ReactiveCocoa or some other FRP framework. However, [ReactiveCocoa 4.0](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/releases) that supports Swift 2 is not production ready. It's in alpha. I don't know what to expect if I have a project that I might ship in a month or two using the alpha version. If I use alpha and use the basics, will it be bug free-ish with only api breaking changes now and then?

If one wants to use Swift 2 and FRP plus ship in a month, what's a smart move here?

How can I get a FRP framework into my new project now and what are the risks?

Other FRP frameworks: [RxSwift](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift), [ReactKit](https://github.com/ReactKit/ReactKit)

Comment: related twitter thread: https://twitter.com/NachoSoto/status/664278822024429568

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see the list of pending issues for `ReactiveCocoa's 4.0` release [here](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue+milestone%3A4.0).

Except for a few potential API changes, and [a minor issue](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/issues/2453) which has a workaround, `4.0` should be ready for production use (I've been using it in production for a while myself).

Considering that, I'd strongly suggest going for `RAC` :)